# How do I do this in PHP..Number formatting

Tags: php, numbers

Hey im sure this is pretty simple..but im not exactly sure how to ask the question so searching the forums were difficult.

I have a variable with a number in it ... lets say $number.....the variable has a single regular number...1 or 2 or 34 or 102 etc

I need to change it to something like this

001, 002, 034, 102

So the first 2 place values are 00 for single digit numbers or 0 of double digits.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Craig

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf).

```
$num = 2;
$num = sprintf("%03u", $num);

echo $num; // prints 002
```

Comment: Thanks guys this was most direct...went with this one...works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

[`str_pad()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
echo str_pad($number,3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this:

```
$number; //your number
$len=strlen($number);
$res="";
for ($i=0; $i<3-$len;$i++)
    $res.="0";
$res.=$number;
```

Comment: why vote down? my answer is as good as any, put it in a function and it probably works like str_pad... granted, I like other answers more- but there is no need to vote down on a perfectly good answer. Love, fingerman.